# Don't let this riddle put you in a foul mood

Tags: riddle, word

> As a verb,
>
> down to the floor
>
> As a noun,
>
> skyward I soar

Comment: Is the title a clue?

Comment: rot13(nofbyhgryl)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm guessing the answer is:

> **DUCK**

*As a verb,*
*down to the floor*

> To 'duck' means to stoop or get down, usually to avoid colliding with something (a bullet, a ball...) or to get a different view.

*As a noun,*
*skyward I soar*

> Although a duck is commonly a water*fowl* (explaining the title pun with 'foul') it can also fly, and thus 'soar skyward'.

Comment: Yes, that was my intent.  Nice solve!

Answer (score 10):

A guess:

> Quail

As a verb,

down to the floor

> To quail is to be frightened and intimidated, and possibly shrink down to the ground

As a noun,

skyward I soar

> A quail is also a bird that is able to fly

And the title

> Foul is a pun on fowl

Comment: Close, but not quite the answer I had in mind

Answer (score 4):

> Is the answer up? For the first two lines Up is part of the verb 'to upset' and your heart feels like it is heavy and so sinking 'down to the floor' and up is a noun which of which 'soaring skywards' is a plausible definition. As for the title same reason as the first two lines upset means to be in a bad mood.

Comment: Nope, I like your thinking, but this wasn't the answer I had in mind

Answer (score 3):

WAY too many similar answers available for this one:

I'll put them in each in a single line as:
WORD: verb definition

I'll be omitting noun because they all have the same theme as the accepted answer

1

> **BIRDIE** to play one stroke under par

2

> **DOVE** plunge steeply downward

3

> **DUCK** lower the head or the body quickly

4

> **EAGLE** to play two strokes under par

5

> **GOOSE** to pinch the "bottom"

6

> **HAWK** watching down over something

7

> **KIWI** slang term for a "down under" footballer

8

> **QUAIL** feel or show fear or apprehension / cower down

9

> **RAVEN** or **SWALLOW** to get food down

I had initially thought of 1 through 4 (especially #2) without much thought and after stretching things a bit, I added the other 6.

Comment: I think #2 fits almost just as well

Comment: I like your way of thinking.  #2 is a more clever answer than mine without stretching the wording at all - I should have thought of that one.  #8 works too - that's a word meaning I wasn't familiar with before.  Some of the answers definitely stretch the "to the floor" wording (#6) for example. Still, I think you did a great job showing this one to be too broad - back to the drawing board!  :)

Comment: It won't let me accept two answers, so you'll have to accept just my upvote instead.  Thanks again for the feedback.

Comment: @Nico The accepted answer is very rarely done "to the floor" but more often done "down", making it a reason why I didn't answer early.  Based on this now being accepted as the answer, I took it to be just a way to make it rhyme and that was the reason why I showed so many others that would fit with "downward" or "down" (which would be another neat play on words).